# How can one make <input> to show *** instead as plain text

Tags: javascript, forms, join, concatenation

I want *id=demo* `(/document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML)` for the value *myInput3* to output like  `****`.

The current behaviour shows the value of *myInput3* in plain text.

i.e. If I enter `abcd1234` in *myInput3*, I want to see `********` in *id=demo*

```html
<script>

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("myInput2").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("myInput3").value;
  document.getElementById("myInput3").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your details are: " + x;
}


</script>

<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<div>Name:</div> <div><input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()"></div>
<div>Username:</div> <div><input type="text" id="myInput2" oninput="myFunction()"></div>
<div>Password:</div> <div><input type="password" id="myInput3" oninput="myFunction()"><div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `The current behaviour prints 'myInput3' in plaintext.` if you want a breaking html char then do you desire `<br/>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repeat the character (`*`) up to the length of the character in the password field using [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```
 var pass = document.getElementById("myInput3").value.trim();
 pass = '*'.repeat(pass.length);
```

```html
<script>

function myFunction() {
  var pass = document.getElementById("myInput3").value.trim();
  pass = '*'.repeat(pass.length);
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("myInput2").value + ' ' + pass;
  document.getElementById("myInput3").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your details are: " + x;
}


</script>

<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<div>Name:</div> <div><input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()"></div>
<div>Username:</div> <div><input type="text" id="myInput2" oninput="myFunction()"></div>
<div>Password:</div> <div><input type="password" id="myInput3" oninput="myFunction()"><div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to replace all characters in the password like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value + ' ' + 
  document.getElementById("myInput2").value + ' ' + 
  document.getElementById("myInput3").value.replace(/[\S]/g, "*")
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your details are: " + x;
}


</script>

<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<div>Name:</div> <div><input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()"></div>
<div>Username:</div> <div><input type="text" id="myInput2" oninput="myFunction()"></div>
<div>Password:</div> <div><input type="password" id="myInput3" oninput="myFunction()"><div>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("myInput2").value + ' ' + document.getElementById("myInput3").value.replace(/[\S]/g, "*")
  document.getElementById("myInput3").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your details are: " + x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<div>Name:</div> <div><input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()"></div>
<div>Username:</div> <div><input type="text" id="myInput2" oninput="myFunction()"></div>
<div>Password:</div> <div><input type="password" id="myInput3" oninput="myFunction()"><div>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very much welcome! Would be good if you accept the answer :D Thank youuu!